# How to correctly inherit arguments from parent to child class?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

Is there a way to instantiate a child class that inherits all arguments from the parent class AND adds new arguments while:

- keeping the argument order intact;
- not requiring keyword arguments;
- changing with the parent class?

Or is this an unconventional/unpythonic thing to do?

The following minimal-working example should explain my question more clearly.

Thanks in advance!

```
class Parent:
    '''
    Sample Parent class.
    
    Arguments
    ---------
    arg1: int
        Sample argument 1.
    arg2: int
        Sample argument 2.
    arg3: int
        Sample argument 3.
    '''
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
        
        
class Child(Parent):
    '''
    Sample Child class.
    
    Arguments
    ---------
    arg1: int
        Sample argument 1.
    arg2: int
        Sample argument 2.
    arg3: int
        Sample argument 3.
    arg4: int
        Sample argument 4.
    '''
    # THIS CHANGES THE ORDER OF THE ARGUMENTS (arg4 is first.)
    def __init__(self, arg4, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.arg4 = arg4
    
    # THIS MAKES arg4 A KEYWORD-ONLY ARGUMENT.
    def __init__(self, *args, arg4):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.arg4 = arg4
        
    # THIS REQUIRES MANUAL CHANGES IF THE PARENT CHANGES.
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        self.arg4 = arg4
```

Comment: This seems unconventional. What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's the context? Beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For example, maybe it'd be better to use composition over inheritance.

Comment: I am working on code to support integration of a spectrophotometer device. I created a class 'Spectrum' which contains all general properties of a spectrum i.e., (i) which chemical is measured; (ii) a pd.DataFrame containing the measurement data.

I created child classes TransmittanceSpectrum and AbsorbanceSpectrum which add more detailed parameters such as spectrumtype, peaks, absorbance_max...

Should the parent and child have the same arguments?

I am not familiar with the term 'composition'. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the parent class to also use `*args`

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.arg1 = args[0]
    self.arg2 = args[1]
    self.arg3 = args[2]
```

And then the child:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)
    self.arg4 = args[-1]
```

This will pass all args to the parent but it would use only the first 3. The child will use only the last element in args

Comment: Careful, this actually requires **three or more** arguments. If you provide three, `arg3` and `arg4` will be the same. If you provide more than four, `args[3:-1]` will be ignored. I'm not sure how to fix that except something like `assert len(args) == 4`, which would require changing with the parent class, so it doesn't really fit OP's requirements.

Comment: Op wanted to avoid editing the parent class when, they didn’t mention not editing the child. Other than that you are right but given that op wants to use *args i.e. there’s ambiguity about the input arguments I think this is appropriate